# How to fitBounds groundOverlay google maps api more closely

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fitbounds

I created a groundOverlay that uses the Google Maps API. I'd like to make the ground fit much as possible. I also tried to use `padding` option or `zoom++` but it not work as I expected.

Current:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Re-production: https://jsfiddle.net/abinhho/5kvtfpeo/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite easy to understand. `fitBounds()` will fit the map to the given bounds and make sure the entire bounds are visible within the map viewport. So it will choose the best zoom level (and center point) to achieve that.

It might display with a good margin around, but would not fit anymore if you zoom in one more level. Try it with the below example.

```js
var historicalOverlay;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 40.740, lng: -74.18},
    zoomControl: true
  });

  var imageBounds = {
    north: 40.773941,
    south: 40.712216,
    east: -74.12544,
    west: -74.22655
  };
  
  historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      'https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
      imageBounds);
      
  historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
  
  map.fitBounds(historicalOverlay.getBounds());
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

The only thing you *could* do about that, is to use the [`padding`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#Padding) interface, maybe with a negative value. But then you might have the opposite result; the image might not be shown entirely.

```js
var historicalOverlay;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 40.740, lng: -74.18},
    zoomControl: true
  });

  var imageBounds = {
    north: 40.773941,
    south: 40.712216,
    east: -74.12544,
    west: -74.22655
  };
  
  historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      'https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
      imageBounds);
      
  historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
  
  map.fitBounds(historicalOverlay.getBounds(), {'bottom': -50, 'left': -50, 'top': -50, 'right': -50});
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's same with zoom++ result.

Comment: What did you not understand from my answer? Why would it help incrementing the zoom level? You will **not** get a perfect fit, unless you know and can control the size of the map container **and** the size of the overlay. In which case it's just a matter of finding the right numbers (you wouldn't even need to use `fitBounds()` for that...).

Comment: Yes I understand your mean that we could not make a perfect fit if we use `fitBounds`. So, have to find other work around.

Comment: If you could increment the zoom level by 0.5 or even smaller values, you could probably find a better fit but since you can't... I don't think you will find a workaround. At least not with documented API methods AFAICT.

Comment: I am considering uses `leaflet` but not sure. Anyway, thank you!